# Multithreading operation in JSP

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, parallel-processing

I am trying to build something, which requires multithreading functionality. The desired work was not done using javascript i.e. **Web-Workers**.
So I changed focus from javascript to JSP. Now I want to call one method which will execute series of some queries, and at the same time I want to show the affected table rows on other hand. And when first process done with it's execution, I want to stop other process also.
 My work is done but statically. Now I want to share some resource between this two threads. So that when first thread done with it's execution, I will set some value to that resource(variable,flag), and check that resource in another thread. Is it possible to access variable of one thread in another while it running.
Thanks

Comment: Do the queries result in heavy processing directly in the javascript, or some asynchronous waiting on another process?  If the latter, you probably want to look into promises and callbacks.

Comment: Have you looked at [WorkerExchange](https://github.com/steelbrain/Worker-Exchange)?

Comment: If the former, then check out **web workers** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Both the process will run parallel just 2nd one is depends on first. James Thorpe

Comment: I need to check with Worker. Thanks user1620220 & JonSG

Comment: It seems I don't have any access to DOM objects using WebWorkers.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript in a browser is per design not capable of multithreading. You can simulate it a little bit when using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) or [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) methods.

But, as with the introduction of HTML5, there are now so called [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) available. They run completely separate, spawn a real OS thread, do not have access the DOM but can interact with your UI application e.g. via events.

Comment: It seems I don't have any access to DOM objects using **WebWorkers**.

Comment: Thats mentioned in the answer. But you can interact with the Main UI thread via e.g. events.